# How would I import these es6 exports? Are they named exports or default?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I was looking at this code from the Material UI project that seems to `export` a series of React Components:

`src/Dialog/index.js`:

```
export { default } from './Dialog';
export { default as DialogActions } from './DialogActions';
export { default as DialogTitle } from './DialogTitle';
export { default as DialogContent } from './DialogContent';
export { default as DialogContentText } from './DialogContentText';
export { default as withResponsiveFullScreen } from './withResponsiveFullScreen';
```

What would an import statement look like if I was trying to these? Are they importing the module and exporting them on the same line? Why not just use the `export default Dialog` syntax?

Comment: To do something like `import { DialogActions, DialogTitle, DialogContent } from './Dialog/index'` ?

Comment: @NanduKalidindi yeah and that's where I'm confused. Why are we importing these as named exports (using the `{`) if we're exporting the `default` ?

Comment: You can always use `import DialogActions from './DialogActions'` but may be they decided to expose all the exports from a single file, to make it easier for end users to do multiple module imports without having to write multiple import statements.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the same as an import and then a named export.

This snippet:

```
export { default as DialogActions } from './DialogActions';
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```
import DialogActions from './DialogActions';
export DialogActions;
```

If you wanted to use that in your file, you would could use a named import like so:

```
import { DialogActions } from './src/Dialog/index.js'
```

Comment: yeah and that's where I'm confused. Why are we importing these as named exports (using the `{`) if we're exporting a `default` module, like in the snippet you provided: 
```import DialogActions from './DialogActions';
export DialogActions;```

Comment: To me this looks like a design choice by them so that you can `import * from '...'` a single file to get all of these exports rather than having an import per file.

This could also be done to ensure proper module loading order if they contain side effects, but I don't think that's the case here.

Comment: So THAT's where I'm confused:
- `DialogActions` is a default export, but I have to import it as a named export?
`import { DialogActions } from './src/Dialog/index.js'`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it let you import and re-export modules using a single `export` statement, it's part of babel `stage-1` preset and is called [export extensions](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-export-extensions/)

---

`export default from './Dialog'` is valid too see : https://github.com/tc39/proposal-export-default-from#exporting-a-default-as-default

Answer (score 0):

`index.js` is "magic", and means "exports of this directory". This lets you group a bunch of related stuff into a directory and be able to import directly from the dir path. In your example, it has one default export of `Dialog`, and the others as named exports. So you would import such as:

```
import Dialog, { DialogTitle, DialogContent } from `path/to/DialogModule`
```

This is nicer to use than if you did not have an `index.js`:

```
import Dialog from 'path/to/DialogModule/Dialog/Dialog'
import Dialog from 'path/to/DialogModule/DialogTitle/DialogTitle'
import Dialog from 'path/to/DialogModule/DialogContent/DialogContent'
```

It's also a convenient way to specify what is intended to be exposed to users of that module. There could be 50 other files in the directory, and those wouldn't be visible when importing from `path/to/DialogModule`. **This is particularly useful if `index.js` is the main export of an npm module.** Only those exports would be visible (`import`able) to another project using that module. There could be a bunch of other stuff in the same dir that they don't intend for users.

E.g. the file structure could be:

```
DialogModule/
├── actions.js
├── Dialog
│   ├── Dialog.css
│   ├── Dialog.js
│   ├── Dialog.test.js
│   └── index.js
├── DialogActions
│   ├── DialogActions.css
│   ├── DialogActions.js
│   ├── DialogActions.test.js
│   └── index.js
├── DialogContent
│   ├── DialogContent.css
│   ├── DialogContent.js
│   ├── DialogContent.test.js
│   └── index.js
├── DialogContentText
│   ├── DialogContentText.css
│   ├── DialogContentText.js
│   ├── DialogContentText.test.js
│   └── index.js
├── DialogTitle
│   ├── DialogTitle.css
│   ├── DialogTitle.js
│   ├── DialogTitle.test.js
│   └── index.js
├── index.js
├── SecretComponent1
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── SecretComponent1.css
│   ├── SecretComponent1.js
│   └── SecretComponent1.test.js
├── SecretComponent2
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── SecretComponent2.css
│   ├── SecretComponent2.js
│   └── SecretComponent2.test.js
├── util
└── util.test.js
```